# question about order of multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I have a question regarding... I guess the order of multiplication.

$$(2x-1)(x+4)$$
So we are trying to find what $x$ makes this equation equal $0$. So obviously we have to have either the first part, or the second part, or both to be $0$ for the whole equation to be equal to $0$.

But I'm a little confused about something.
Aren't we supposed to multiply the following? $$2x(x)$$ $$2x(4)$$ $$-1(x)$$ $$-1(4)$$ But in the book it says I should calculate out the parentheses first. For example say $$x = 1/2$$ then $$(2*1/2-1) = 0$$ and THEN $(0)(x+4)$ But how is this possible if we need to multiply by $(2x-1)(x+4$) first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you have right there, is a quadratic polynomial.

$$(2x-1)(x+4)=0 \Leftrightarrow 2x^2 + 7x-4=0$$

**If** quadratic polynomial $P(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ has roots $x_1,x_2$, it can be factorized in the form of :

$$P(x)= (x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$

This is what you have in your initial expression. Truly, if you execute the multiplication, you'll get the expanded form of your quadratic. But having the factorized form is instantly straight-forward to yield you the roots of the expression.

True, it is :

$$(2x-1)(x+4)=0$$

Then, since you have an expression like $A \cdot B = 0$, either $A$ or $B$ or both should be equal to $0$. Applying this to your specific problem, means that :

$$(2x-1)=0\Rightarrow x=1/2$$

$$(x+4)=0\Rightarrow x=-4$$

Which are the solutions $x_1,x_2$ of your quadratic and it's the reason the expanded form of it can be written as that.

There is a general form of calculating the roots of any quadratic polynomial $P(x)=ax^2 + bx + c$ and the roots are given by the formula :

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

**if and only if** the discriminant $D\geq 0$. If $D < 0$ the equation $ax^2 + bx + c=0$ will not have **real** solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication of two numbers is $0$ when one of them is $0$. Since $(2x-1)$ and $(x+4)$ are numbers that are multiplying one of them must be $0$ for the product to be 0.

This implies $$\text{Either} \quad 2x-1=0 \\ \text{or} \quad x+4 = 0$$
Both can't be ) zero simultaneously as $x$ can take only one value at a time. You need to multiply if you want to find the quadratic function. Using the quadratic function coefficients you can calculate the roots using that formula. $$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ for a quadratic equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$.